# How to create a dictionary with awk in Linux?

Tags: linux, awk

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir Dictionary
for litera in {A..Z}; do
cd Dictionary
echo > $litera.txt
cd ..
awk '{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        print $litera;
        if(match(tolower($i), "^$litera")) {
            print $i;
        } 
    }
}' myfile | sort > Dictionary/$litera.txt
```

done
exit 0

myfile has the text: `I have apples`

The problem is that in the awk method `$litera = I have apples`

I want it to have: I, h, a ,v , e etc.

What I essentially want is to take all the words from myfile and putem them in the Dictionary folder, each word on its corresponding file.

Output:

```
A.txt : apple

I.txt: I

H.txt: have
```

The rest will be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be made to work using `gawk` or `awk` as follows:

```
$echo "I have an apple"| gawk -F "" '{print $3}'
h

$echo "I have an apple"| awk -F "" '{print $3}'
h

$echo "I have an apple"| awk'{split($0,array,"")} END{print array[3]}'
h
```